# MAX7221 with multiple LEDs per point

Tags: led, led-driver, led-matrix, max7219

I am using a MAX7219/MAX7221 chip in a keyboard design in order to light up the individual keys. The keyboard is going to have exactly 64 keys so with the 8x8 matrix the chip handles I will be able to put one led under every key.

However, I think the space bar is too wide to be lit by a single led, I think 3 would be more appropriate but then how can I connect 3 leds to the same matrix point? Is it enough to put them in series? Do I need some helper circuit? Of course a key requirement is that these 3 leds are as bright as the other ones.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could consider using a second chip which might give you additional freedoms in your design. The cloned ones are relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put 3 in series, the voltage drop will be too high. If you put 3 in parallel, even if you solve the voltage matching issue, you will only get 1/3 the current in each.

The left circuit is how the IC is intended to be used, there is one LED at each SEG and DIG intersection.

The right circuit is a potential solution. Unfortunately, when you use a non-standard connection, the parameters you need are not always specified. It is difficult to know how predictable the current source will be in this circuit. Without a sufficient load, it won't be able to put out the specified current. It should put out a voltage near 5V as it attempts to put out the specified current, but you may need to run some experiments.

If you are only building one, an experiment would be sufficient. If you are designing a product, this would be risky. They could change the design while still meeting the datasheet; but affecting your non-standard design.

You will need to select the resistor value to match the current in the other LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdym00.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting I would have to hijack the chip like that. Would it be a good idea to connect a resistor between SEG and ground to make sure a sufficient load is present? I'm going to make a PCB and I'd rather leave a component unmounted rather than having to hack one in ;). Anyway this is going to be an open source "product", if things inside the chip change people will be able to update it accordingly.

Comment: @SukkoPera - adding a load resistor on the SEG signal to ground that sets the voltage to 3.5 or 4.0 volts might help get a more predictable voltage at the emitter (and therefore more predictable LED current). But, if you are using LEDs with a high voltage drop (white), you may not have sufficient voltage leftover.

Comment: I see. What if I replace the BJT with a MOSFET?

Comment: @SukkoPera - N-channel MOSFET: no. P-channel MOSFET: maybe, but more risk of weird things happening than an NPN. And, the logic will be reversed.

Comment: @SukkoPera - If you can characterize the output with various resistive loads, it will be easier to determine the best solution. Use a scope since the signal is multiplexed.

Comment: Found a MAX7219 chip (probably clone) in my stash and been experimenting a bit: your proposed circuit works, looks like no resistor is needed, as I tried 10k and 1k with no noticeable changes in brightness or scope. Using a small one (220) actually makes everything dim. Thanks a lot!